# Extract FileName from a given path

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am working on MS Access and trying to extract just the filenames from a complete file path.
Example, consider the column names in the table:

```
Path               | Directory   |  FileName  | extension
---------------------------------------------------------
C:\temp\xyz.txt    | C:\temp     |  xyz       |   txt
C:\myPath\tp.doc   | C:\myPath   |  tp        |   doc
```

In the Access query design view, I am using the following for generating the the "Directory" values:

```
 Left([Path],(InStrRev([Path],"\")))
```

I am not able to extract the correct values for the FileName and extension columns. Any ideas that could do the exact without having to write it in a module would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mid()` with those other functions to get the file base name.  And `Right()` should be useful to get the extension.

```vb
Path = "C:\temp\xyz.txt"
? Mid(Path, InStrRev(Path,"\") + 1, InStrRev(Path,".") - InStrRev(Path,"\") - 1)
xyz
? Right(Path, Len(Path) - InstrRev(Path, "."))
txt

Path = "C:\myPath\tp.doc"
? Mid(Path, InStrRev(Path,"\") + 1, InStrRev(Path,".") - InStrRev(Path,"\") - 1)
tp
? Right(Path, Len(Path) - InstrRev(Path, "."))
doc
```

Hope you don't have any compound file extensions like `.tar.gz`.  :-)

Comment: @HansUpThat worked like a charm. :) And yes, I do not have compound extensions that have double dots like you mentioned.